# Ionic 2 pagemodule lazyloading

Tags: ionic

Buenas a todos, 
He generado un proyecto nuevo (blank) de ionic después de actualizar todo.

Añado una pagina (InicioPage) con el generador del cli, y la pongo como pagina de incio en app.components.ts pero al hacer ionic serve me da error:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for InicioPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
noComponentFactoryError@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3682:34

Solo funciona si incluyo en app.module.ts en declarations y entry components InicioPage, que segun veo, no deberia dado que la InicioPage ya tiene su inicio.module.ts

Alguna idea?

---

Buenas @PabloLozano, trato de añadir el modulo en mi app.components.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { InicioPageModule } from '../pages/inicio/InicioPageModule';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    InicioPageModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Pero me da este error:

> Typescript Error Cannot find module
>   '../pages/inicio/InicioPageModule'.

Comment: Está el módulo inicio importado en el módulo app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas,

cuando declaras una página con lazy loading dejas de poder tratarla como un componente y tienes que tratarla como un string.

Es una ñapa de Ionic para distingir los dos casos.

usa comillas.

```
rootPage:any = 'HomePage';
```

en vez del componente.

lo explican bien en el blog: http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/

Para la navegación igual.

```
this.nav.setRoot('TuPaginaConLazy');
```

en vez de

```
this.nav.setRoot(TuPaginaSinLazy);
```

Comment: Has dado en el clavo, no he tenido ni que añadir el modulo al app modules.